# How to enable autoreloading for BOTH js and ts with nodemon?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nodemon

I have a project where we are using javascript. But we want to be able to use typescript too. So I added support for that. And it seems to work. I can add new typescript files, and they work as they should. And whenever I change a typescript file, the app autoreloads thanks to nodemon.

However, somehow I broke the autoreloading of js files.

In `package.json` I have added the dependencies `ts-node`, `@types/node`, `ts-loader` and `typescript`. We also had a file `start.js` that I renamed to `start.ts`, and I changed `"main": "start.js"` to `"main": "start.ts"` and also the script `"dev": "npm install && nodemon -L start"` to `"dev": "npm install && nodemon -L start.ts"`

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json",

  "include": [
    "**/*",
    "foobar/test.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The above seemed to be the minimal needed to get typescript working, both as running code and autoreloading on changes. But somewhere I managed to break autoreloading of js files.

**How do I fix to that I have autoreloading of both?**

The `foobar/test.js` is just a test file I made explicitly to test the autoreloading.

I'm not sure what additional information that might be needed, so don't hesitate to ask for more. I included what I thought might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple. Just add `"allowJs": "true"` to the `tsconfig.json` file

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs

> #### Allow JS - allowJs
>
> Allow JavaScript files to be imported inside your project, instead of just .ts and .tsx files. For example, this JS file:
>
> ```
> // @filename: card.js
> export const defaultCardDeck = "Heart";
> ```
>
> When imported into a TypeScript file will raise an error:
>
> ```
> // @filename: index.ts
> import { defaultCardDeck } from "./card";
>
> console.log(defaultCardDeck);
> ```

Furthermore:

> This flag can be used as a way to incrementally add TypeScript files into JS projects by allowing the .ts and .tsx files to live along-side existing JavaScript files.